# Box2d Collision Detection b/w "b2body & c++ object"

Tags: c++, opengl, box2d, collision-detection, glut

I am developing a projectile shooting game.

*The basic structure of the game is that a tank is controlled by the user using the arrow keys,From right side of the screen an enemy will enter and will start walking towards the tank. The tank will shoot projectile rockets, if it hits the enemy then user scores if the enemy reaches the tank than user loses.*

-Tank movement is implemented using an Animated_Sprite class which is an OpenGL or rather a c++ object named 'hero' created in the main function.
-Enemy movement is also implemented using the same Animated Sprite class which slices the spritesheet into different frames, frames change during the motion of the object using an Update_Sprite_Animation() function. Hence 'enemy' object is also an Animated_Sprite Class object created in the main function.
-With the movement of tank the background also moves in the opposite direction.

**-THE MAIN PROBLEM(for me)-** Rocket(Box2d Circle shape) which will be fired from tank's position) is not an Animated_Class Object, It is made something like this:

```
b2Body* addCircle(int x,int y,int r,bool dyn=true){...}
void drawcircle(b2Vec2 center,float r,float angle){...}
b2Body *mycircle;
float speed=6,angle=300*3.141/180;  ...
```

Then i have applied Linear velocity to 'mycircle' body of box2d to get projectile motion of the rocket(circle) like this:

```
void mouse( int button, int state,int x,int y)
{

           if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
           {

            mycircle=addCircle((hero->x)-5,(hero->y)+3,8,true);
            b2Vec2 vector = speed * b2Vec2(cos(angle), -sin(angle));
            mycircle->SetLinearVelocity(vector);
          }

}
```

-From what i have read, In Box2d the collision between objects is checked by creating two more objects and getting a contact list like this :

```
 for (b2Contact* contact = world->GetContactList(); contact; contact = contact->GetNext())
          contact->... //do something with the contact
```

-Since hero & enemy are not b2body objects but rather Animated_Sprite class objects, what do you suggest i should do? Can I typecast an Animated_Sprite class object to get a b2body object? or do i have to create a new b2body object and give it a reference of hero or enemy objects? If yes than guide me. Or do i have to create a new b2body object and give it all the fixtures of hero & enemy? **There must be a way to detect collision between our own class object outside b2world and a b2body object such as the circle shape of box2d but i am very new to this & I have no clue what to do.**

-The reason for not implementing hero & enemy as Box2d bodies: Because I don't know how to implement the Animated_sprite class animation on b2body objects & the reason i am using box2d for projectile motion is because i don't know how to implement it using raw Opengl.

I cannot read the whole manual of Box2d regarding collision because it would take too much time.

**Direct me and tell me what should i do so that i could detect collision between a b2body object & an object outside b2world i.e normal c++ Opengl object.**

Comment: I have to admit it's not very endearing to say you don't want to read the manual. Do yourself a favor and at least read the section titled 'User data'. http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Comment: Well, Sorry for the silly question. I appended code for a box2d physics body in my Animated_Sprite Class constructor and now every time a new object of Animated_Sprite is instantiated a reference to new physics body is also created with it hence creating the object of Animated_Sprite class basically a physics object of the box2d world also. Now I got what i was aiming for. Thanks

Comment: BTW I followed tutorial on your iforce2d.net site to achieve this, You have excellent tutorials on your website. If anyone wants to know how I did it follow the tutorial on this link "DRAWING YOUR OWN OBJECTS AS PHYSICS BODIES IN THE BOX2d WORLD" > http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/drawing-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[PROBLEM SOLVED]**

In order to detect collision using box2d I think its necessary to have them as box2d bodies rather than only c++ objects. Concurrently making a c++ object as well as mapping it on the Box2d body will solve the problem , Box2d can listen for collisions using its contact listeners. How i made my custom class object into a b2body object is as follows ->

I appended code for a box2d physics body in my Animated_Sprite Class constructor and now every time a new object of Animated_Sprite is instantiated a reference to new physics body is also created with it hence creating the object of Animated_Sprite class basically a physics object of the box2d world also. Now I got what i was aiming for. Thanks –

BTW I followed tutorial on iforce2d.net site to achieve this, They have excellent tutorials. If anyone wants to know how I did it follow the tutorial on this link 
"DRAWING YOUR OWN OBJECTS & CREATING PHYSICS BODIES OF THEM IN THE BOX2d WORLD" >
 iforce2d.net/b2dtut/drawing-objects